# redirecting user to PayPal after submitting the data to db

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, paypal

i have a very frequent situation when submitting a form . I have a form that take order from user and after submitting the form it take user to PayPal for the payment . Issue is that how can i redirect the user to PayPal . I have tried almost all the possible solutions including $.post function of j query , JavaScript double action submission and php query string redirect but no one help me out . Its an humble request to all of you to help me out . just tell me the solution.

Additional : the form is custom and i have created my template to store the data in WordPress. The for is submitting to my database when i change the path of form action to my db path and when i change it to PayPal path its submit it to PayPal but not to my db.

Answer (score 1):

A similar piece of code should work for you, subscriptionFrm is the ID of your form. In my case, index.php returns a JSON string with status about server-side processing (the JSON string is parsed with eval). Of course you need to append all PayPal hidden fields to your current form.

> $(document).ready(function () {
>
> $('#subscriptionFrm input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
>
> ```
>           $.post('index.php', $('#subscriptionFrm').serialize()).done(function (r) {
>                   var result = eval('(' + r + ')');
>                   
>                   /* Check result from your PHP code */
>                   
>                   
>                   $('#subscriptionFrm').attr('action', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
>                   $('#subscriptionFrm').submit();
>           });
>           
>           return false;           }); });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way to redirect to PayPal ,after processing the form's data. So you only should follow the principles in this entry.

First, I've set an action to the WordPress init, from my plugin's code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_init');
```

Now, it is time to implement the 'my_init' function:

```
if( !function_exists( 'my_init' ) ){ // Use function_exists to avoid conflicts
    function my_init(){
        if( $_POST[ 'unique_variable' ]){ // A form field to identify we are processing the form
        //...process here your form
        // and then print the form to be redirected to PayPal
        ?>
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="myform" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@email.com" />
       <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product Name" />
           <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Product Number" />
       <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10" />
       <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
       <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EN" />

       <input type="hidden" name="return" value="URL to the product after check the payment" />
       <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="URL to use if user cancel the payment process" />
       <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="URL of IPN in your website to check the payment" />

       <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
       <input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="Primary" />
       <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
       <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
       <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF" />
       <input type="hidden" name="ipn_test" value="1" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">document.myform.submit();</script>
        <?php
        exit; // It is very important stop the WordPress in this point
        }

    }
}
```

You should modify the values of PayPal form fields, with your email, the URLs to your IPN, cancel and return page, the product's name, number and the amount to be charged.

Pay attention to the "exit" sentence after print the PayPal form, it is required to stop the PHP execution, the document.myform.submit(); submits the PayPal form after be loaded.

An excellent starting point in this subject is the premium version of plugin Calculated Fields Form (http://wordpress.org/plugins/calculated-fields-form/)

;-) Ericko